# Code analysis - Do not dispose object multiple times

Tags: c#, code-analysis

i have tried following the rules of code analysis on this method:

```
public static string Encrypt(string password)
{
    string myPassword = string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        myPassword = password;
        byte[] Value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myPassword);
        SymmetricAlgorithm mCSP = new RijndaelManaged();
        mCSP.Key = _key;
        mCSP.IV = _initVector;
        using (ICryptoTransform ct = mCSP.CreateEncryptor(mCSP.Key, mCSP.IV))
        {
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, ct, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(Value, 0, Value.Length);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                    cs.Close();
                    myPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return myPassword;
}
```

added all the `Try {} Finaly{}` blocks, but it was still yelling at me that i dont respect rule 2202.
anyone can give me a hand with this?

yes, i have read other posts about this subject and tried applying it,
but at the end i still get the same message.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get rid of the CA2202 warning for `cs`, simply remove the call to its `Close` method.

The CA2202 problem for `ms` is a wee bit more complex.  The warning is cropping up because `CryptoStream` has the effrontery to dispose the stream it received via is constructor, which means that there's one inappropriate call to `ms.Close()` that you can't avoid.  The good news is that this untimely disposition has no side-effects in your case, and the same goes for the double disposition, so you can safely slap on a `SuppressMessageAttribute` and ignore the problem.  (For cases where you actually need to passed stream to survive its unpreventable disposition by something like `CryptoStream`, the usual technique is to use a stream subclass whose disposition can be prevented by its instantiating code.)

Comment: i dont really like suppresing any "errors", maybe i should refactor my code?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of these two lines, they aren't needed:

```
cs.FlushFinalBlock();
cs.Close();
```

Comment: And move `myPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());` to the parent scope, to ensure that `cs` **has** been flushed!

Comment: Still getting rule 2202 on `ms`.

Answer (score 2):

Following the [documentation on this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx) should lead to this code:

```
public static string Encrypt(string password)
{
    string myPassword = string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        myPassword = password;
        byte[] Value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myPassword);
        SymmetricAlgorithm mCSP = new RijndaelManaged();
        mCSP.Key = _key;
        mCSP.IV = _initVector;
        using (ICryptoTransform ct = mCSP.CreateEncryptor(mCSP.Key, mCSP.IV))
        {
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = null;
            try
            {
                ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream()
                var tmp = ms;
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, ct, 
                                                       CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    ms = null;

                    cs.Write(Value, 0, Value.Length);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                    cs.Close();
                    myPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(tmp.ToArray());
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if(ms != null)
                    ms.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    return myPassword;
}
```

Comment: Still getting rule 2202 on `cs` and `ms`

Comment: @Dementic What about if you did this, but got rid of the `cs.Close()`? i.e. a combination of our answers

Comment: even a combination of the codes wont work, i still get the 2202 on the `ms`

Comment: with the new edit, `ms` and `cs` throws 2202. i tried all this stuff at home... but i could not figure out why it keeps happening...

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on this analysis warning (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx) gives this example, similar to yours in that it's manipulating streams:

```
Stream stream = null;
try
{
    stream = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        stream = null;
        // Use the writer object...
    }
}
finally
{
    if(stream != null)
        stream.Dispose();
}
```

but this still gives the error. The following will solve the error:

```
Stream stream = null;
StreamWriter writer = null;
try
{
   stream = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
   writer = new StreamWriter(stream))

   // Do some stuff on the stream writer..
}
finally
{
   if(writer != null)
       writer.Dispose();
   else if(stream != null)
       stream.Dispose();
}
```

The reason is simple; if the writer will always dispose the stream for you. Only in the scenario the writer is not successfully created should you dispose the stream yourself. But I must admit I like the following syntax a lot more, and if you create a MemoryStream instead of a FileStream the chance of an exception occurring is small and I would prefer suppressing the CA. Please notice that you can stack using statements, so a extra 'nesting level' is often not required.

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    // Use the writer object...
}
```

Comment: you like digging up graves? ;) 
if the stream is not successfully created, then there is no need to dispose it.. suppression, as i commented in the answer above, is not something i like to do. i managed to fix the code by re-factoring my code.